# How to extract particular record from QuerySet using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Lets say: I have `views.py`. Here `Employees` is the model class having some fields like: name, email, pass, mobile etc.

```py
def login(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':

     emp = Employees.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'],
           password=request.POST['password'])
     
     if emp:

      # Now here I'm getting confused how to get particular record like id, 
      # email, pass from emp var to store in session. 

       request.session['id'] = emp[0].id    # here is the main problem
       request.session['email'] = emp[0].email
       stmt1
       stmt2
       return redirect('/homepage')  
     else:
       return render(request, 'forms/login.html')
  else:

     stmt1
     stmt2
```

At the last I'm saying that this is the hint what I want to get from the
queryset. Please don't ask why I'm doing that stuff of coding. I might be
wrong, so please ignore my mistakes and give me the best way to do that only
what I found problem # so sharing with you all.

Comment: Employees return a queryset, you need check if `exists()` or get the first and unique result `Employees.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'],
       password=request.POST['password']).first()`

Comment: # If I give reference of PHP code so it would be like :


 $sql = " SELECT * FROM student_tbl WHERE (email= '" . $email . "' ) AND 
 password = '" . md5($password) . "' ";

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or mysqli_error($conn);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

 $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
 $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

# Please corelate my question to this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting a single object to be returned, you can use a `try/except` block alongside `objects.get()`

Something like:

```py
try:
    employee = Employee.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'],password=request.POST['password']
    return redirect('/homepage')
except Employee.DoesNotExist:
    return render(request, 'forms/login.html')
```

Comment: I'm using filter() to match the record which is entered using the html form and match that to the record inside the database. But if I use get() so how will match the record.

Comment: What will happen?  We are only putting try... except to get an error but problem will be remain same. Please find the comment above for @Diego about my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#examples) of sessions with Django, there are many things done and with little code you don't worry.

This an example:

```
def login(request):
   m = Member.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])

   if m.password == request.POST['password']:
       request.session['member_id'] = m.id
       return HttpResponse("You're logged in.")
   else:
       return HttpResponse("Your username and password didn't match.")
```

Translate with your code:

```
def login(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      emp = Employees.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'],password=request.POST['password']).first()
 
   if emp:
      request.session['id'] = emp.id
      request.session['email'] = emp.email
      return redirect('/homepage')  
   else:
     return render(request, 'forms/login.html')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying but I'm using filter() to check the values coming from the html login form. 
This line as you wrote :

'm = Member.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])'

how will it check. It will give only the result based on username.

My requirement is that once user filled username and password then check that values in the database and based on that values extract the id, email in the session to use in another page.

Can you please give me the code for this requirement? I just don't want the algorithm, please take a while and give the code if possible